# Qt5 convert chars to 8bits unsigned values

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have 2 ways I used to convert characters to their representing 8bit byte values. In the first one it gives correct answer but in second it gives an extra 0 so I had to `ba.size()-1`.
My question is why do I have to do that in second one? I do know this most likely will be the /0 terminator. If im not wrong? Also is there any better way to do this?

```
    // very simple test if we can take bytes and get them in decimal (0-255)format:
    QByteArray ba("down came the glitches and burnt us in ditches and we slept after we ate our dead...");
    for (int i = 0; i < ba.size(); ++i)
    qDebug() << "Bytes are: "<< static_cast<quint8>(ba[i]);
    // very simple second way to do it...
    int j = 0;
    while (j < ba.size()-1){
    qDebug() << "Bytes are: "<< static_cast<quint8>(ba[++j]);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't both ways have same exact results? that's the main question in-case it wasn't clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is because of invalid use of increment operation. When you use `++j` you already has value `1`, so you never get the `0` index. Also you get the last index bigger then the array size. The right way is:

```
qDebug() << "Bytes are: "<< static_cast<quint8>(ba[j++]);
```